# Is it possible to interface ZMPT101B AC voltage sensor with STM32?

Tags: stm32

I will be making a capstone project and this is my first time working with the said component. That being said, I'm having a hard time looking for references online where a ZMPT101b was interfaced with an stm32. There are lots of data available online but it's always being interfaced with Arduino.  If so, what are considerations that I should make (safety, ADC, etc)?

I have experience with ADC in STM32f411RE before using a light sensor. Can I use the code from previous ADC projects before to build the code for this one? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this can be done.